# Adding padding within a div and the background image and color go away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

First off let me say how much of a big help this website has been with my little project. Anyway on to my question.

So right now I'm creating a personal website for myself and I want to add some padding to something, but when I add padding, it ends up creating space between some stuff and making it completely white without using the background image or color. This is what I mean.

[When I open up the "About" tab (I added padding to that one but not the one above), do you see how there's a lot of white space? How can I have that colored in grey and use the background image aswell?](https://gyazo.com/0dbedc5c27b72033711a1556d5ea72da)

[And when I close the tab, there is a big white gap, which is (I'm pretty sure) the padding not closing](https://gyazo.com/e0f191c035f46852a2229e60ae3d1edb)

I only added padding to the "About" tab and as you can see, it is messed up compared to the others [(This is the jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/69oazx7j/)

```
.small2{
font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
font-size: 30px;
padding: 15px;
margin: auto;
}
```

This is the css code for the class holding the info.

Comment: Why can't you give the background color to the same element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ar8twqvw/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Nice! So that works when I expand the component, but when it's closed, there's still the liddle odd space inbetween About and Projects. Is there anyway of hiding that or removing it and showing it when the content is expanded maybe? Or anyway to fix that I mean

Comment: whether all the header elements and content elements have the same style

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ar8twqvw/2/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the padding to the .four class, I think it will give you your desired result.

Comment: Wow, that fixed every problem! Thank you so much haha, can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: No problem! Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 1):

Take the padding off `.two`, and if you want the white border around the content in `.four`, you can use a margin:

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  $('.one').click(function() {
    $('.two').slideToggle();
  })


  $('.three').click(function() {
    $('.four').slideToggle();
  })

  $('.five').click(function() {
    $('.six').slideToggle();
  })


  $('.seven').click(function() {
    $('.eight').slideToggle();
  })

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.two').slideToggle();
  }, 500);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.one {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #605F5F;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.two {
  background-color: #333333;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
}
.three {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #605F5F;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.four {
  background-color: #333333;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
  margin: 15px;
}
.five {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #605F5F;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.six {
  background-color: #333333;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.seven {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #605F5F;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.eight {
  background-color: #333333;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.botbar {
  background-color: #2b2a2a;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
}
.big1 {
  font-family: 'Megrim', serif;
  font-size: 210px;
}
.small1 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
  font-size: 80px;
}
.small2 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-clip: initial;
  margin: auto;
}
.botinfo {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big1">
    <div class="one">Main</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small1">
    <div class="two">Welcome to my page!
      <br>Click around
      <br>Learn a thing or two about me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="big1">
    <div class="three">About</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small2">
    <div class="four">My name is Bob and I currently attend University of Bob.
      <br>If a passionate student that is always trying to learn new and exciting things and broaden their knowledge in the field of programming is someone you need, then I'm your guy.
      <br>I have worked on projects ranging from this website that was created by yours truly, a game of solitaire with my own personal twist, and much more.
      <br>All my projects can be found in the tab below!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="big1">
    <div class="five">Projects</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small1">
    <div class="six">My projects can be found here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="big1">
    <div class="seven">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="small1">
    <div class="eight">You can contact me here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="botinfo">
    <div class="botbar">Made by Bob | Copyright 2016</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do some restructuring of the code to simplify it like

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {

  $('.header').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.content').slideToggle();
  })

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.content').first().slideToggle();
  }, 500);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #605F5F;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
  color: white;
}
.content {
  background-color: #333333;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
}
.botbar {
  background-color: #2b2a2a;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("noise.png");
}
.big1 {
  font-family: 'Megrim', serif;
  font-size: 210px;
}
.small1 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
  font-size: 80px;
}
.small2 {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-clip: initial;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
}
.botinfo {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="big1 header">
    Main
  </div>
  <div class="small1 content">
    Welcome to my page!
    <br>Click around
    <br>Learn a thing or two about me
  </div>
  <div class="big1 header">
    About
  </div>
  <div class="small2 content">
    My name is Bob and I currently attend University of Bob.
    <br>If a passionate student that is always trying to learn new and exciting things and broaden their knowledge in the field of programming is someone you need, then I'm your guy.
    <br>I have worked on projects ranging from this website that was created by yours truly, a game of solitaire with my own personal twist, and much more.
    <br>All my projects can be found in the tab below!
  </div>
  <div class="big1 header">
    Projects
  </div>
  <div class="small1 content">
    My projects can be found here
  </div>
  <div class="big1 header">
    Contact
  </div>
  <div class="small1 content">
    You can contact me here
  </div>
  <div class="botinfo">
    <div class="botbar">Made by Bob | Copyright 2016</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display : none;` for `.small2` in css. Even though it is hidden it is taking space on UI. (if you need padding when visible)

```
.small2{
font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
font-size: 30px;
background-clip: initial;
padding: 15px;
margin: auto;
display : none;
}
```